# Create dynamic object with public properties

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an object that is created inline but i want to acces the properties i create inside like the folowing:

```
object x = new { text = "one", text2 = "two" };

if (x.text == "one") //can not acces this item in the object
{ 
    //do somthing
}
```

I know i can make this work by creating a `dynamic` object but then i need to realy make sure i spell the property correct and i dont want that.
What happend with this code is that i cant acces the properties inside, how can i do this without using a dynamic object and having the chance to misstype the property name?

Comment: `object x = new { text = "one", text2 = "two" };` --> `var x = new { text = "one", text2 = "two" };`

Comment: You're looking for an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: Could it be that the reason to use `dynamic` instead of `var` here is to pass that object outside the scope of the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `var` as the type of your variable instead:

```
var x = new { text = "one", text2 = "two" };

Console.WriteLine(x.text); // Fine, and suggested by Intellisense
Console.WriteLine(x.text1); // Compile-time error
```

Note that this isn't really a "dynamic object" in that the property names and types are known at *compile-time*. All that's happening is that the C# compiler is creating a type for you automatically with the relevant properties (and constructors, and overrides of `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`). The name of that type is unspeakable in C#, but `var` lets you declare a local variable of that type, allowing compile-time checking etc.

The `var` feature is known as [*implicitly-typed local variables*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

The `new { ... }` feature is known as [*anonymous types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
`dynamic test = new { text = "one", text2 = "two" };
 var result = test.text;`
```